# Combining the if-else-if condition to a logical expression

Tags: shell-script

Is the following expression correct way to combine the if-else if statement?

```
 if [ $TO_MAJOR -eq 7 ] ; then
   if [ $TO_MINOR -eq 3 -a $TO_PATCH -lt 2 ]; then
    echo "AE port not supported"

    elif [ $TO_MINOR -lt 3 ] ; then
            echo "AE port not supported"
    fi
 fi
```

to

```
 if [ [ $TO_MAJOR -eq 7 ] -a [ [ $TO_MINOR -eq 3 -a $TO_PATCH -lt 2 ] -o [ $TO_MINOR -lt 3 ] ] ]; then
        echo "AE port not supported"
        fi
```

Comment: Don't mix `[[` and `[`: stick to `[[`...

Comment: @jasonwryan I have edit it in the question. Can i use '( )' ?

Comment: That code is not a valid sh script.  Maybe instead of `else` you want `elif`?

Comment: @jasonwryan but that's only for bash/ksh/zsh hmms?

Comment: @h.j.k. Well OP had one `[[`, so presumably (absent any other information like a shebang) his shell accomodates that construct (and if it does, they should use it).

Comment: @jasonwryan ah ok, didn't see the revisions...

Answer (score 1):

You have too many brackets in the second code.  `[` is synonymous with `test`.  So there are two ways to do what you want.  One is to do it all within a single test statement, in which case there is only one set of brackets:

```
if [ \( $TO_MAJOR -eq 7 -a $TO_MINOR -eq 3 -a $TO_PATCH -lt 2 \) -o $TO_MINOR -lt 3 ]; then
```

The other is to use the shell's `&&` and `||` operators to connect multiple test commands

```
if [ $TO_MAJOR -eq 7 ] && ...
```

But what you have doesn't work because while `[` is synonymous with `test`, `[` doesn't make sense within a `test` statement.

Comment: I have one more doubt- can we replace && with -a ?

Comment: -a is a test operator && is a shell operator.  So you aren't replacing one with the other.  They are just different strategies.  Do you want to and the results of a bunch of executions of `test`, or do you want a single `test` that computes the conjunction of a bunch of conditions?

Comment: Your second method worked like charm. I just wanted to 'and' the first if condition with rest of test conditions.

Comment: In your fist test, the case `$TO_MAJOR -eq 7 -a $TO_MINOR -lt 3` is not given, as it's  only `-o $TO_MINOR -lt 3`